# How can I view the tasks which are assigned to my organizational team members?

Tags: ms-project-2013, project-server

I am a team lead and we are using Microsoft Project Server 2013. My team members have many tasks assigned across different projects. How can I view the tasked assigned to my team members within SharePoint?

We are only an organizational team, not a project team defined in Microsoft Project server.

Comment: I havent use MS project Server before, but I think Jira is really easy to use. You can try it for sometime and compare the two.

Comment: Thats not what i asked for

Comment: You can most probably create a filter (custom view). Someone at your organization probably knows the tricks to sharepoint and ms project. (I didn't use project + sharepoint). I have custom filters for watching out my teammates' works.

Answer (score 0):

In MS Project you can create a filter (custom view). 
[Here's Microsoft web page telling how.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-custom-filter-282de296-6e05-4d99-86c6-96be04bc00dd)

If you want to do a filter on sharepoint side, Your sharepoint or project server admin most probably knows the tricks to sharepoint and ms project integration.

I didn't use project + Sharepoint setup myself, but I saw some companies using a web view of Ms Project in Sharepoint. Adding tasks and viewing them. In this case you can filter your team members.

I have custom filters for watching out my teammates' tasks. It's quite useful.